# .net 6 mvc AntiForgeryToken fails to verify

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, antiforgerytoken

I am working on a .net 6 MVC web app as the front-end with a .net 6 web api project as the back-end.

There's a function which makes an AJAX POST call to fetch data, and it works smoothly with a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the request. The Token is placed in the data with other parameters. The break point in my controller was triggered as expected.

View: (pretty sure this is the only token in this view)

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Ajax: (this works fine)

```
function ProductSearch() {
    var token = $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/MyController/SearchProduct")',
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token.val(),
            data: $('#data').val()
        },
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.IsSuccess === false) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: res.Message,
                    showConfirmButton: true
                })
            }
            else {                        
                $("#divToBeReplaced").html('');
                $("#divToBeReplaced").html(res);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            CloseLoading();
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'error',
                showConfirmButton: true,
                timer: 1500
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchProduct(string? data)
{
        ...
}
```

However, the other AJAX request I'm working on, using the same `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` mentioned above, fails to post to the controller, and gets a HTTP 400 error right away.
Similar to the previous AJAX, the CSRF token was placed in AJAX data:
(tried putting it in the header and still failed)

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/MyController/DeleteCheckedProduct")',
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', token);
    },
    data: {
        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
        delList: delList
    },
    ...
```

the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCheckedProduct(string delList)
{
    ...
}
```

Maybe the `Program.cs` setting something that affects my AJAX post?

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    //options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); → commented
})
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString;
});
```

As you can see, this seems to be a simple problem, two Ajax functions are almost the same, I still cannot figure out why the second AJAX Fails to Request. Any clue will be appreciated, Thanks!

Tried sending the post request without the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on the DeleteCheckedProduct Action, and it worked just fine.

**EDIT:**
Also found out the `ProductSearch()` succeeded only the first try. When I trigger this function again, I got a HTTP 400 error too.
For your information, `MyController/SearchProduct` returns a PartialView. When the AJAX request is success, the returned partial view will replace the existing  like  `$("#divToBeReplaced").html(res);`.
Is there something about the partial view I guess?

Comment: In your first  AJAX, you set `__RequestVerificationToken: token.val(),`  , but second ajax, you set `request.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', token);` have a try with `token.val()`.

Comment: @QingGuo Thanks for reminding me the `token` param that I missed to post, already editted my question above. The `token` variable is already asigned `$('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();`

Comment: " When I trigger this function again, I got a HTTP 400 error too." What's your error message ? Try to use `F12`  to see the code in the source tab, and set a breakpoint at `__RequestVerificationToken: token.val(),`, can you see the value  when you trigger this function again?

Comment: @QingGuo Yes, I can see the token value, and the token values are identical when I do both AJAX requests. The 400 error message goes like:
"POST https://localhost:7213/MyController/DeleteCheckedProduct 400
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
DeleteCheckedProduct  @ MyController:323
onclick @ MyController:1"
And I tried searching for some info, but still, it only indicates that the error originated from the AJAX call, nothing useful.

Comment: I cannot see the link content. If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: don't add it to the header or change the header.  Also be aware that this token should only work once, by design.  Each form will generate a new one.  There is also a cookie involved here.  If the ajax call has a custom header and/or is cross site, you need to specify withCredentials: true.  If the data returned to AJAX is form content, be sure it also contains the anti-forgery token.  ex: @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Comment: ...also make sure there's not 2 after the DOM update.  You could be grabbing the old one if it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the script sends the token in a header called `RequestVerificationToken`, In Program.cs, configure the antiforgery service to look for the `RequestVerificationToken` header:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken");
```

Comment: Is this work ? If not, where do you define this ajax ? Besides, you also can use `F12` to see the code in the source tab, and set a breakpoint at `request.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', token);` to see the token value.

Comment: The Ajax request is in the `<scripts>` section, which is in the same View where I defined my `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. Also, I tried modifying the header's name of the AntiForgeryToken to match with my AJAX call, and still failed the request, getting a HTTP 400 error.